# Using icons in Android preferences

Tags: android, resources, settings

I would like some of my preferences to have icons, like the Settings app.

I guess one way of doing this would be to copy all the relevant code and resources from the Settings app, but it seems like overkill for a couple of icons.

Also I don't like the idea of having to duplicate the code and resources in each project that requires settings icons.

Has anyone solved this already with a simpler or resource-free approach?

Comment: I don't get it, why can't you just use a custom layout? http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/Preference.html#setLayoutResource%28int%29

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The Settings application uses a private custom `PreferenceScreen` subclass to have the icon -- `IconPreferenceScreen`. It is 51 lines of code, including the comments, though it also requires some custom attributes. The simplest option is to clone all of that into your project, even though you do not like that.

[source code](http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/packages/apps/Settings.git;a=summary)

Comment: If only resources could be shared between projects. I kind of hoped someone solved this already and wrapped it in a nice class without any external resources.

Comment: It should be noted that the Settings app approach extends Preference, not PreferenceScreen and that it also requires a custom layout to work.

Comment: @Shine: I didn't put the link there in the first place. http://androidxref.com/source/xref/packages/apps/Settings/src/com/android/settings/IconPreferenceScreen.java

Answer (score 7):

Since API level 11 you can add icon to preferences:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/Preference.html#setIcon%28int%29

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/Preference.html#attr_android:icon

For older Android versions, you have to use custom layouts and bind images in code, as @roger-l suggests.

Comment: What is the icon resolution that's needed for it?

Comment: I used 32x32 dip

Comment: With some padding? Or exactly this size for the content?

Answer (score 5):

Updated.... answered and working

Use a custom layout for the icon preference

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:id="@+android:id/widget_frame"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
     android:gravity="center_vertical"
     android:paddingRight="?android:attr/scrollbarSize">
     <ImageView
         android:id="@+id/icon"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_marginLeft="6dip"
         android:layout_marginRight="6dip"
         android:layout_gravity="center" />
     <RelativeLayout
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_marginLeft="2dip"
         android:layout_marginRight="6dip"
         android:layout_marginTop="6dip"
         android:layout_marginBottom="6dip"
         android:layout_weight="1">
         <TextView android:id="@+android:id/title"
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:singleLine="true"
             android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
             android:ellipsize="marquee"
             android:fadingEdge="horizontal" />
         <TextView android:id="@+android:id/summary"
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:layout_below="@android:id/title"
             android:layout_alignLeft="@android:id/title"
             android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
             android:maxLines="2" />
     </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

and the imported class for IconPreferenceScreen

```
public class IconPreferenceScreen extends Preference {
    private final Drawable mIcon;
    private static String mType;

    public IconPreferenceScreen(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int iconRes) {
        this(context, attrs, 0, iconRes);
    }
    public IconPreferenceScreen(Context context, AttributeSet attrs,
            int defStyle, int iconRes) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        setLayoutResource(R.layout.preference_icon);
        mIcon = context.getResources().getDrawable(iconRes);
    }
    public IconPreferenceScreen(Context context, int iconRes) {
        this(context, null, iconRes);
    }
    @Override
    public void onBindView(View view) {
        super.onBindView(view);
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.icon);
        if (imageView != null && mIcon != null) {
            imageView.setImageDrawable(mIcon);
        }
    }
}
```

then you can just use a new IconPreferenceScreen in place of a Preference, and add an icon

Comment: Check in attrs.xml of the Settings app.

Answer (score 1):

Android 3.x Honeycomb shows icons defined in standard Preferences.

So probably the use of icon depends on Android OS version or screen size.

Comment: It depends on Android version, see my answer above.